# Regex get text between the html tags - PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, tags, preg-match

```
function teste(){
    $string = '<div>Hello, i am João</div><a href="test/test.com">testttttttttttt</a>';
    $matches = array();

    preg_match('/<[^>]*>/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    print_r($matches);exit();
}
```

I am having a little problem with Regex, I just want to get the text from everything that is between the html tags (including the tags) and create an array with those results, however, I'm not able to save the result to the array.

Basically, I need the following return:

```
Array(
     [0] => <div>
     [1] => </div>
     [2] => <a href="test/test.com">
     [3] => </a>
)
```

Comment: There's a [pt.so] site available in Portuguese.

Comment: (Welcome to (finally) *posting* on SO!) (`preg_match()` may match greedily.) Please present in your question what result you *are getting*. (`sorry for…` never apologise for what you are. Do your best (e.g. use a spelling checker and capitalise *I* in mid-sentence, too), and don't ever feel second best for failing (save that for *not trying*).)

Comment: Parsing HTML using regular expressions is probably the wrong approach in the long term.  You can often get it to work in very basic examples, enough for you to think it's a good idea.  But then you try it on some html that's more complicated than your basic contrived examples, and you end up with a horrid mess of code full of exceptions, case statements, etc.  I would look for an existing library that does HTML parsing already, unless you'll only ever need to "parse" simple HTML strings like in your example.

Comment: I don't really know if i have to use this function, i have a function that will read a HTML text Backend, and i don't know if this library ignores HTML tags, so, if i have a problem with that, my plan is:
 - get all HTML tags;
 - Convert these tags into a number (With one of my functions)
 - And convert again these numbers to HTML tags

Comment: I am getting all HTML tags in text with this function... well, everything that is between tags, but, considering that my text editor will convert others tags into '&lt;', that will work fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php function teste(){
    $string = '<div>Hello, i am João</div><a 
   href="test/test.com">testttttttttttt</a>';
   $matches = array();

    preg_match_all('/<[^>]*>/', $string, $matches);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: Reallyyyyy thank you man!
This works for me in parts to be honest, i removed your 'echo "<pre>"' because it didn´t work for me, insted of that, i change the last line of the code for "print_r(html_escape($matches));"

My function was working, but i was not seeing this because of the HTML...

Really Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome, it has been my pleasure helping you out!